# Not working mysql_query in php (quotation marks probs)

Tags: mysql, quotes

```
$ikona = "layout/achiv/a_icon.png";
//$opis = string of text without quotation marks

$addit = '<img src="'.$ikona.'" onclick="alert(/'On day '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' user has '.htmlspecialchars($opis).'/'); ">';

mysql_query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `this_damn_cell`='".$addit."'
WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."' ") or die(mysql_error()); //error is not showing up

echo $addit; //shows correctly
```

It seems to work okay, but in sql base nothing is getting added. All fields exists. this_damn_cell type is TEXT
For any assistance thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code reads MySQL Injection all along.

For a quick-fix with [`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) please change your code to the following:

```
$sql = sprintf('UPDATE accounts 
                SET this_damn_cell = %s
                WHERE id='%i", mysql_escape_string($addit), mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']);

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //error is not showing up
```

But do read a bit on prepared statements. Using PDO or MySQLi.

[Taken from PHP site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) this is a simple example of using MySQL with binding (which does prevent MySQL injection and the sort of errors you're facing).

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

Comment: I needed add a little improvments, but it works fine. Thanks! :)